# How to draw BarChart with MySQL data in React native?

Tags: php, sql, react-native, svg, react-native-svg

I need to draw a chart with MySQL server data.

I found this example, but when I try to put my dynamic data it's not working:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BarChart, Grid } from 'react-native-svg-charts'
import * as shape from 'd3-shape'
import { BarChart, Grid } from 'react-native-svg-charts'

export default class FetchExample extends React.Component {

    //Function to recupere my data from my php file ///////////////////////////////////
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={ isLoading: true}
      }

      componentDidMount(){
        return fetch('https://127.168.1.4/graph.php')
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {

            this.setState({
              isLoading: false,
              dataSource: responseJson,
            }, function(){

            });

          })
          .catch((error) =>{
            console.error(error);
          });
      }
    //here I return a static data ////////////////////////////
              render() {
                  const fill = 'rgb(134, 65, 244)'
                  const data = [50, 10, 40, 95, -4, -24, null, 85, undefined, 0, 35, 53, -53, 24, 50, -20, -80]

                  return (
                      <BarChart style={{ height: 200 }} data={data} svg={{ fill }} contentInset={{ top: 30, bottom: 30 }}>
                          <Grid />
                      </BarChart>
                  )
              }
          }
```

I use PHP as backend to fetch data:

```
<?php

$serverName="DESKTOP-T5SLVUB\SQL2008R2";
$connectionInfo=array("Database"=>"Netos_DB","UID"=>"sa","PWD"=>"123");
$conn=sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);   
$sql = "select ChiffreAffaire from V502_client where Mois=2 and Annee=2020 "; 
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql  );
  while( $row[] = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      $Item = $row;
      $json = json_encode($Item);}
    echo $json;

?>
```

The result of this PHP file:

```
[{"ChiffreAffaire":"4800.00"},{"ChiffreAffaire":"12000.00"},{"ChiffreAffaire":"1200.00"},{"ChiffreAffaire":"10032.00"}]
```

How can I replace data (static data) with MySQL data that I fetch in my PHP file?

Comment: I can see that you are setting the data in `datasource`  but where are you using it?

Comment: I want use it instead of data but I don't know how

Comment: that is because you have not declared the state for `dataSource` in  ` constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={ isLoading: true}
      }` and also the data in `BarChart` expects data in array you are giving an array but in key value pair.

Comment: also take a look at https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts-examples

Comment: I declared  my dataSource in constructor but I didn't understand the second part of ur answer

Comment: the BarChart is expecting  only values `const data = [50, 10, 40, 95, -4, -24, null, 85, undefined, 0, 35, 53, -53, 24, 50, -20, -80]` but you are supplying in key value in dataSource `[{"ChiffreAffaire":"4800.00"},{"ChiffreAffaire":"12000.00"},{"ChiffreAffaire":"1200.00"},{"ChiffreAffaire":"10032.00"}]`

Comment: it is expecting array of values but you are supplying array of objects

Comment: AAAAh okay !!!! so there is any solution to transform my data

Comment: that can be achieved with a simple for loop `for(var i = 0; i < dataSource.length; i++) {
    delete dataSource[i]['ChiffreAffaire'];
}`
 but its better if you get the exact data from the server

Comment: I'm really stuck here !! Im kind of beginner and I need to do this graph asap ;if you have any suggestion please help me